# About incoherent waves inteference

Tags: waves

When incoherent waves overlap each other, is this mathematically strictly proven that the intensity of the incoherent waves simply adds the intensity of the two waves?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If one wave is represented by a $u_1(t,x) = A_1\cos(\omega_1t+\phi_1(x))$ and the other by $u_1(t,x) = A_2\cos(\omega_2t+\phi_2(x))$ and you add them, linear superposition, you get $u(t,x) = A_1\cos(\omega_1t+\phi_1(x)) + A_2\cos(\omega_2t+\phi_2(x))$.

The *instantaneous* intensity of the wave is $\lvert u(t,x) \rvert^2$ that fluctuates in time at the rate of order at least $\max[\omega_1, \omega_2]$. To make sense out of it, the *time* average of $\lvert u(t,x) \rvert^2$ is taken to which sensors, detectors can respond.
$$\mathcal P = \langle \lvert u(t,x) \rvert^2\rangle = \lim_{T\to\infty} \frac{1}{T}\int_0^T \lvert u(t,x) \rvert ^2dt\\
\lim_{T\to\infty} \frac{1}{T}\int_0^T A_1^2 \cos^2(\omega_1t+\phi_1(x)) + A_2^2 \cos^2(\omega_2t+\phi_2(x))+2A_1A_2 \cos(\omega_1t+\phi_1(x))\cos(\omega_2t+\phi_2(x))dt\\
=\frac{1}{2}A_1^2+\frac{1}{2}A_2^2$$
In practice, this means that $\mathcal P$ is essentially independent of $\omega_1$ and $\omega_2$ if $T\lvert \omega_1-\omega_2 \rvert >>1$ which condition is satisfied by having the square-law detector be followed by a low pass "video" filter that does the integration has "RC time constant" set equal to $T$.

Comment: thank you for answering me