# Mathematically, how exactly is $\langle \vert(E_m + E_r) \vert^2 \rangle$ calculated?

Tags: electromagnetism, interferometry, photonics

In a section on interferometry, my photonics textbook says the following:

> Now, let's consider the signal obtained at the output of the interferometer. In general, the fields returned on the photodetector from the measurement and reference arms can be written in the form of rotating vectors, or $E_m = \mathrm{E}_m \exp i(\omega t + \phi_m)$ and $E_r = \mathrm{E}_r \exp i(\omega t + \phi_r)$.
> The photodetector current is the average of the square modulus of the total field, or $I_\text{ph} = \sigma \langle \vert(E_m + E_r) \vert^2 \rangle$, where $\sigma$ is a conversion factor and the brackets $\langle .. \rangle$ denote averaging.

Mathematically, how exactly is $\langle \vert(E_m + E_r) \vert^2 \rangle$ calculated? What exactly is meant by "averaging" here? I'm familiar with the concept of "[time average](https://astronomy.swin.edu.au/cosmos/t/Time+Average)," but I'm not totally clear that that's what the author means here.

Comment: Which textbook?

Comment: @rob Appendix A2 **Basic Optical Interferometers** of *Electro-Optical Instrumentation: Sensing and Measuring with Lasers* by Silvano Donati.

Comment: I would guess you do a time average. If you invoke the ergodic assumption, this is equivalent to doing an ensemble average of many repetitions of the experiment

Comment: @QuantumMechanic Yes, I suspect the author was referring to the time average.

Comment: As in this answer (https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/745048/about-incoherent-waves-inteference/745065?noredirect=1#comment1669683_745065) but make $\omega_1=\omega_2$ (you asked for the coherent case) and then take the limit. If you insist on using the complex amplitude notation let $E_1\bar E_2$ for the *product* of the cosine terms.

Comment: @hyportnex My textbook has $I_\text{ph} = \sigma \langle \vert(E_m + E_r) \vert^2 \rangle = \sigma \langle \mathrm{E}_m^2 + \mathrm{E}_r^2 + 2 \mathrm{E}_m \mathrm{E}_r \text{Re}\{ \exp i(\phi_m - \phi_r) \} \rangle = I_m + I_r + 2(I_m I_r)^{1/2} \langle \cos(\phi_m - \phi_r)\rangle$. Can you please explain how your $A_1^2 \cos^2(\omega_1t+\phi_1(x)) + A_2^2 \cos^2(\omega_2t+\phi_2(x))+2A_1A_2 \cos(\omega_1t+\phi_1(x))\cos(\omega_2t+\phi_2(x))$ relates to my $\mathrm{E}_m^2 + \mathrm{E}_r^2 + 2 \mathrm{E}_m \mathrm{E}_r \text{Re}\{ \exp i(\phi_m - \phi_r) \}$?

Comment: That is right, and that is what you get aside from a factor of $2$ from the real variable version if you use $\Re e^{\mathfrak j x}=cos(x)$. I leave it to you to find the reason for that factor $2$; it also shows up as normalizer in the definitios of "rms" power, "effective" power, envelope power, etc.

Comment: @hyportnex Are you sure these are both the same thing? Isn't $\mathrm{E}$ the amplitude, which would be equal to your $A$? There seems to be something materially different between these, since yours also has the $\cos^2(\omega t+\phi(x))$ factor as part of the term, whereas mine (the author's) only has the $\mathrm{E}^2$ as the term on its own, with no cosine factor.

Comment: Recall that $cos^2(x)=\frac{ 1+cos2x}{2}$, now what is its average when taken over $x \in [-A,A]$ and $A\to \infty$?

Comment: @hyportnex Never mind. I just had to expand everything out properly (using Euler's formula) and then use the appropriate trig identities to simplify.